# Parity conservation in particle decay

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, angular-momentum, nuclear-physics, parity

I currently have a problem where a decay calculation $J^P=(1/2)^+$ decays into a meson $0^-$ and a nucleon $(1/2)^+$. While $J = L + S$ is conserved, it still appears that parity isn't. $L=0$ in this case. Is this consistent with $N(1440)\rightarrow \pi + N$ where $N$ is any nucleon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your evidence that this decay has orbital angular momentum $L=0$? I'm prepared to disbelieve your question and state that in the decay $N\to N\pi$ the orbital angular momentum is $p$-wave, not $s$-wave, for exactly the reason you state in your question: strong decays conserve parity.

Remember that angular momentum addition gives $\vec J = \vec L + \vec S$, not necessarily $J=L+S$.

The [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/tables/rpp2015-sum-baryons.pdf) doesn't assign an orbital angular momentum to $N\to N\pi$, which is their usual approach when only one value of $L$ is allowed.
However the following decay branches do have specific orbital angular momenta called out:
\begin{align} 
N(1440)1/2^+ &\to \Delta(1232)3/2^+ + \pi(140)0^-
& \text{$p$-wave only}
\\
N(1520)3/2^- &\to \Delta(1232)3/2^+ + \pi(140)0^-
& \text{$s$- and $d$-wave}
\\
N(1535)1/2^- &\to \Delta(1232)3/2^+ + \pi(140)0^-
& \text{$d$-wave only}
\\
N(1680)5/2^+ &\to \Delta(1232)3/2^+ + \pi(140)0^-
& \text{$p$- and $f$-wave}
\end{align}

Notice that only the parity-conserving values of $L$ are allowed, and that the $d$- and $f$-wave decays can't be explained unless you use vector addition of angular momentum.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I actually just had confusion with how the orbital angular momentum works. Got it sorted out now though!